# facebook application to store data (mp3)

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3

I would like to develop a facebook app (using as3) where the output is xml files and mp3 files.  what are the recommended way of doing so ?

From small research I did I came up with these options so far:
convert xml files to sql tables , store the mp3 as a blob using facebook sql //  is that allowed?  what is the size limit for the table?

use amazon cloud service ?  // up tp 5gb free but I would rather find a completely free option.

Thanks

Comment: Will it be simplier to add the mp3 file to Dropbox? Then have your AC3 read off the dropbox's metadata and output in xml?

Comment: Hi Alvin , How much can I store in a dropbox account ?  I was looking more of a way where the data can be hosted in the users data storage. Like in Mobile apps where you can store data in the users applicationDirectory, is there such a thing in facebook?   Thanks

Comment: Facebook doesn't have storage facility, you can use dropbox (2gb), sky-drive (5gb), live-kive (5gb) and recently, Box.net offers 50GB free for Apple mobile devices only :(

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was searching for a while and could not find - facebook doesn't have storage , makes sense and good to know!  If you can add it as an answer so I can accept, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook doesn't have storage facility, you can use dropbox (2gb), sky-drive (5gb), live-kive (5gb) and recently, Box.net offers 50GB free for Apple mobile devices only :(